# How to combine 2 Android projects on eclipse?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-manifest

I added the first project as a library. Then, i added this library to the second project. Now, in the second project, i need to move from an activity to another one in the first project (The app. crashes in this step, however both projects are working well).I tried this link http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html steps but no change. Also, i tried to add the files of the first project to the second project, but the same problem appears.
Logcat error:

```
09-02 19:33:21.437: E/AndroidRuntime(27777): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-02 19:33:21.437: E/AndroidRuntime(27777): Process: com.vatrina.eg, PID: 27777
09-02 19:33:21.437: E/AndroidRuntime(27777): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vatrina.eg/com.vatrina.eg.CustomizedListView}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
09-02 19:33:21.437: E/AndroidRuntime(27777):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
09-02 19:33:21.437: E/AndroidRuntime(27777):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
09-02 19:33:21.437: E/AndroidRuntime(27777):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
09-02 19:33:21.437: E/AndroidRuntime(27777):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
09-02 19:33:21.437: E/AndroidRuntime(27777):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-02 19:33:21.437: E/AndroidRuntime(27777):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
09-02 19:33:21.437: E/AndroidRuntime(27777):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
09-02 19:33:21.437: E/AndroidRuntime(27777):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-02 19:33:21.437: E/AndroidRuntime(27777):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-02 19:33:21.437: E/AndroidRuntime(27777):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
09-02 19:33:21.437: E/AndroidRuntime(27777):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
09-02 19:33:21.437: E/AndroidRuntime(27777):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-02 19:33:21.437: E/AndroidRuntime(27777): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
09-02 19:33:21.437: E/AndroidRuntime(27777):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1156)
09-02 19:33:21.437: E/AndroidRuntime(27777):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
09-02 19:33:21.437: E/AndroidRuntime(27777):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
09-02 19:33:21.437: E/AndroidRuntime(27777):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
09-02 19:33:21.437: E/AndroidRuntime(27777):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
09-02 19:33:21.437: E/AndroidRuntime(27777):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
09-02 19:33:21.437: E/AndroidRuntime(27777):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
09-02 19:33:21.437: E/AndroidRuntime(27777):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
09-02 19:33:21.437: E/AndroidRuntime(27777):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:670)
09-02 19:33:21.437: E/AndroidRuntime(27777):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:509)
09-02 19:33:21.437: E/AndroidRuntime(27777):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
09-02 19:33:21.437: E/AndroidRuntime(27777):    at com.vatrina.eg.XMLParser.getXmlFromUrl(XMLParser.java:45)
09-02 19:33:21.437: E/AndroidRuntime(27777):    at com.vatrina.eg.CustomizedListView.onCreate(CustomizedListView.java:41)
09-02 19:33:21.437: E/AndroidRuntime(27777):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
09-02 19:33:21.437: E/AndroidRuntime(27777):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
09-02 19:33:21.437: E/AndroidRuntime(27777):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
09-02 19:33:21.437: E/AndroidRuntime(27777):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: HI, welcome to Stackoverflow :), post some code and the messages displayed in the LogCat. " in the second, i need to move from an activity to another one in the first project" do you mean that you are trying to load an activity from the library?

Comment: Thanks for your respond. :) Done. Yes, i need to move to an activity in the Library.

Comment: Can you review your code and check if you are performing any connections on the UIThread? I think that's the problem. One of them at least.

Comment: Each Project is working well separately.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that you have not declared the activity from the libary in your main project android manifest file.

Like this:

```
   <application>

     <activity
        android:name="com.libary.activity.example"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
     </activity>

    </application>
```

But i am just guessing here. Please post the error message and code.

---

UPDATE

From looking at the error message `Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`

It seems as valbertos mentioned that the customizedlistview activity  is preforming network operations on the UIThread.

A really nasty quick fix would be to add this to customizedlistview activity.

```
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

But only do this temporally as it causes a lag in the UI.

It's a much better to put all the network operations in a AsyncTask.

Click [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html) for a a good tut on the AsyncTask.

Comment: I need to move from the **Vatrina** project (Main project) **HomeFragment** activity to **CustomizedListView** project (from the library) is **CustomizedListView** activity. Error is added. Also, i declared the activity in the Main project Manifest but no change.
`<application>
    <activity
            android:name="com.library.vatrina.eg.CustomizedListView"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
    </activity>
<application>`